# Default function to read all files in a python folder

Tags: python, directory

Is there any standard function or method in python that reads all files from the directory where the python source program is located? Example: Let be the follow code bellow:

```
import glob, os
from os.path import isfile

def namesARCHIVES(): 
    listNames = []
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\author\archives")
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        listNames.append(file)
```

The method `os.chdir(r"C:\Users\author\archives")` "reads" the directory that contains all the files I need. The python file you compile is in the same folder. Is there any method that does not need to enter the directory of the files as they are in the same folder as the source code? I don't know if it was well explained

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: why not use ```cwd = os.getcwd()```?

Comment: _The method os.chdir(r"C:\Users\author\archives") "reads" the directory that contains all the files I need._ I know you put quotes around the word "reads", but even as an approximation I'm not sure I understand how that makes sense. _Is there any method that does not need to enter the directory of the files as they are in the same folder as the source code?_ All of them, I imagine. This seems like  a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382) to me, can you explain what you actually need to do?

Comment: Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

The path name of the current source file is stored in the `__file__` variable, with which you can use `os.path.dirname` to obtain the directory that the source file is located. Also, `glob.glob` returns a list already, so you don't need to iterate through it just to append the items to another list:

```
listNames = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below would fix your sample script. With glob.glob there is no need to specify the directory if the script is located on that directory and the files and folders that you want to get are also on this directory. The `*.txt` is enough.

It also includes file checking. As it is possible that a directory has a name that ends in txt such as myfolder.txt, that is a directory and not a file.

#### Fixing your sample code

```
import glob
from os.path import isfile

def namesARCHIVES(): 
    listNames = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        if isfile(file):
            listNames.append(file)
    return listNames

names = namesARCHIVES()
print(names)
```

#### Alternative

We can also use the pathlib module.

```
"""Using pathlib module in Python 3.4 and newer."""
import pathlib

directory = ''  # c:\sample
text_files = []

for path in pathlib.Path(directory).iterdir():
    # Show the full path of the files and dir names. If the directory is the
    # current working directory, only the file and dir names will be shown.
    # print(f'path: {path}')

    # Save the file names that ends in .txt.
    # We use is_file() to verify that it is a file because
    # it is possible that a directory name has a .txt extension.
    # The path.name returns the file name of the path.
    if path.is_file() and path.name.endswith('.txt'):
        text_files.append(path.name)

print(text_files)
```

#### References

- [Python glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)
- [Python pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)
- There is an interesting article in coderlegion about [different ways in reading files in a directory](https://coderlegion.com/27/read-all-files-in-a-directory-in-python). It might interest you.